# Testing correlations between different varibles from two measurements

Tags: correlation, experiment-design, biostatistics

The field study investigates the relationship between root traits and plant performance traits in 12 genotypes, using a randomized complete block design with four replications per location.

Root traits, such as root depth and weight, were measured early in the growing season at a fixed time (BBCH 30), referred to as VAR1. Plant performance traits, including leaf area index, flowering date, NDVI, and yield, among others, were measured throughout the growing season or at harvest (VAR2). The objective is to identify correlations between the measured root traits (VAR1) and plant growth traits (VAR2) throughout the growing season.

I am uncertain about the appropriate statistical test to apply for an accurate correlation analysis between different variables from two datasets.